# Lighting in Cycles is not working properly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, lighting

When I try to work with Cycles my lighting doesn't show up and I see nothing in my viewport.

[image]

But when I switch to EEVEE everything works properly:

[image]

But when I try to render I get my model lighted but not by my light set up:

[image]

I am pretty new in Blender and I know I must be doing something wrong but I have no idea where is the problem.

You can download the file in this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b6gHCYrIMrZFlJPKN0PrO1KmQaP2eyqV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can u please provide your blend file?

Comment: There it is!! thank you!!  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b6gHCYrIMrZFlJPKN0PrO1KmQaP2eyqV/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

On the top right corner there is a play button:

[image]

This enables/disables viewport rendering, clicking it should start previewing your viewport render on cycles

Comment: Thank you Zophiekat!! you are right, once I disable the play button I am able to see my render on cycles in my viewport. But my light setup is still not working with the skin texture, it is as if the skin texture were not affected by the lights, but my lights are working in the eyes textures. Do you know what it could be the problem? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: there are lighting differences in eevee and cycles, make sure your light is set up to be able to affect diffuse. or make sure the skin material has the output node set as "All" or "Cycles". you could also look at the meshe's visibility tab and see if some shading stuff is disabled, take note this tab is only visible with cycles